# How to stop a endBy in Parsec

Tags: haskell, parsec

I'm trying to write a csv-like parser using Parsec. So far so good.
The parser decode the header and process everything fine.
Now, I'm trying to skip some comments at the beginning of the file. The comment starts with `#` (or empty line).
If I do that, the `endBy` loop doesn't when the header start but instead fails.

Here is my code:

```
csvParser = do
   -- skipping comment bit
   P.endBy ((P.char '#' >> P.many (P.noneOf "\n"))
            <|> P.many P.space
           ) eol

   -- real parsing starting
   header <- parseHeader
   eol
   case header of
       ["style", "number", "quantity", "length", "width", "height"] -> parsePL
       otherwise -> error $ "Can't decore following header:" ++ (show header)


   where parseHeader = P.sepBy cell sep
         sep = P.char ','
         eol = P.char '\n'
         cell = P.many (P.noneOf ",\n")
         cellp = do x <- cell ; sep; return x
         today = "2015/01/15" :: Date

         readR :: String -> Rational
         readR x = toRational x' where
                   x' = read x :: Float
         parsePL = P.endBy (do
               style <- cellp
               numberOfBox <- read <$> cellp
               numberPerBox <- cellp
               length <- readR <$> cellp
               width <-  readR <$> cellp
               height <- readR <$> cell

               return (style, numberOfBox, length, width, height, "", 0, "",  today)
               ) eol
```

Comment: Looks like a word or two are missing in the last sentence. What exactly you feed, what you expect and what you get? Can you minimize the code snippet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem: `space` includes line-feed, `'\n'`.